# Why Does Constants Big-O Rule Apply Only To Positive, Monotonic, and Non-decreasing Functions Always?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I know that for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions, f(n) and g(n),

```
f(n) = O(g(n) + c) entails
f(n) = O(g(n))
```

Why does this **always** true only for positive monotonically non-decreasing functions?

If there exists one, give a counter-example that shows that the above Big O rule is not necessarily always true for functions that are **not** monotonically non-decreasing.

I'm really confused why the rule specifies only positive, monotonic, non-decreasing functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Monotonicity isn't necessary.

Comment: This is not a full answer but an example you might want to consider is $f(n)=\mid \sin n\mid = O(\mid\cos n\mid +1)$ but $f(n)=\mid\sin n\mid \neq O(\mid\cos n\mid)$. The first statement is easy to see. For the second statement we only have to note that for any scaling factor, $\alpha$ that we choose, $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1>\alpha\mid\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\mid=0$.

Comment: f(n) = g(n) = c or f(n) = g(n) = c + 1/n are also counterexamples. Actually the first one is even a counterexample to the case where f and g are positive and non-decreasing.

Comment: Cross posted at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166807/big-o-constants-rule-question-for-not-monotonically-non-decreasing-functions